# In-text Citations: Same Paragraph With 3-5 Authors

Tags: academic-writing, citations, apa

In nearing the completion of a piece of writing, a question has come up. With the APA format for referencing, consider the following example in a single paragraph.

> .... in the act of breathing (Person A, Person B, & Person C, 2019). Person A et al. (2019)....

Is this citation correct? I am aware that if the in-text citation appeared before that in parentheses:

> e.g. Person A, Person B, and Person C (2019).... in the act of breathing (Person A et al., 2019)

then this would be considered an appropriate instance. But is my first example still correct?

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE Stuart, glad you found us.  Please check out our [tour] and [help].  I edited a couple grammatical bits of your question.  Please make sure I didn't change the meaning of anything by accident.

Comment: What is the discipline? In science you should be able to rephrase the second sentence and avoid this issue entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Both seem fine to me. My only hesitation would be if the 2nd example is a single sentence, then you probably wouldn't need to in-line cite again at the end.

Other than the APA manual, I typically use Purdue as an APA resource as it covers most of the common issues you'll face.

In [In-line text citations:](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/research_and_citation/apa_style/apa_formatting_and_style_guide/in_text_citations_author_authors.html)

> **A Work by Three to Five Authors:** List all the authors in the signal
>   phrase or in parentheses the first time you cite the source. Use the
>   word "and" between the authors' names within the text and use the
>   ampersand in parentheses.